# How to move an ASCII art drawing in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to make a triangle move left and/or right, by only 1 space.

```
cout << setw(10) << "*" <<  endl;
cout << setw(9) << "*" << setw(2) << "*" <<  endl;
cout << setw(8) << "*" << setw(4) << "*" <<  endl;
cout << setw(7) << "*" << setw(6) << "*" <<  endl;
cout << setw(6) << "*" << setw(8) << "*" <<  endl;
cout << setw(5) << "*" << setw(10) << "*" <<  endl;
cout << setw(4) << "*" << setw(12) << "*" <<  endl;
cout << setw(3) << "*" << setw(14) << "*" <<  endl;
cout << setw(2) << "*" << setw(16) << "*" <<  endl;
cout << setfill('*') << setw(19) << "*" << endl;

while(ch = 'a','d'){
    cout << "Enter: 'a' move left, 'd' move right" << endl;
    cin >> ch;

    if(ch == 'a'){
    cout.setf(ios::left);
```

The code above, shows what the triangle looks like. So basically I want an user to enter 'a' [move left] and/or 'b' [move right]. How do I program it, so it moves the entire triangle to move 1 space, either left or right, while retaining the shape?

Based on what I looked at, using cout.setf(ios::left) would be easiest, but I don't know how to do that yet.

Comment: Most probably, by `while(ch = 'a','d')` you mean `while(ch == 'a' || ch == 'd')`.

Answer (score 0):

Using cout for graphics will always be a little bit strange. It is not really designed for drawing / animation.

You could try something like this (using some functions to print the triangle repeatedly from inside your while loop) :

```
void print_triangle(int n)
{
    cout << setw(n + 10) << "*" <<  endl;
    cout << setw(n + 9) << "*" << setw(2) << "*" <<  endl;
    cout << setw(n + 8) << "*" << setw(4) << "*" <<  endl;
    cout << setw(n + 7) << "*" << setw(6) << "*" <<  endl;
    cout << setw(n + 6) << "*" << setw(8) << "*" <<  endl;
    cout << setw(n + 5) << "*" << setw(10) << "*" <<  endl;
    cout << setw(n + 4) << "*" << setw(12) << "*" <<  endl;
    cout << setw(n + 3) << "*" << setw(14) << "*" <<  endl;
    cout << setw(n + 2) << "*" << setw(16) << "*" <<  endl;
    cout << setfill('*') << setw(19) << "*" << endl;
}

void clear_screen()
{
    cout << string( 100, '\n' );
}
```

used like :

```
int n = 0;
while(ch == 'a' || ch == 'd'){
    clear_screen();
    print_triangle(n);
    cout << "Enter: 'a' move left, 'd' move right" << endl;
    cin >> ch;

    if(ch == 'a'){
        n++;
    } else if(ch == 'd'){
        n--;
    }
}
```